# GCloud: Failed to pull image (400) - Permission "artifactregistry.repositories.downloadArtifacts" denied

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud

My pod can't be created because of the following problem:

```
Failed to pull image "europe-west3-docker.pkg.dev/<PROJECT_ID>/<REPO_NAME>/my-app:1.0.0": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://europe-west3-docker.pkg.dev/v2/<PROJECT_ID>/<REPO_NAME>/my-app/manifests/1.0.0: denied: Permission "artifactregistry.repositories.downloadArtifacts" denied on resource "projects/<PROJECT_ID>/locations/europe-west3/repositories/<REPO_NAME>" (or it may not exist)
```

I've never experienced anything like it. Maybe someone can help me out.

Here is what I did:

1. I set up a standrd Kubernetes cluster on Google Cloud in the Zone `europe-west-3-a`
2. I started to follow the steps described here https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/hello-app
3. I built the docker imager and pushed it to the Artifcats repository
4. I can confirm the repo and the image are present, both in the Google Console as well as pulling the image with docker
5. Now I want to deploy my app, here is the deployment file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-app
  labels:
    app: my-app
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-app
        image: europe-west3-docker.pkg.dev/<PROJECT_ID>/<REPO_NAME>/my-app:1.0.0
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
```

6. The pod fails to create due to the error mentioned above.

What am I missing?

Comment: If the image really does exist in that location, the error suggests that the cluster('s service account) does not have access to artifact registry. This should be enabled by default **if** the cluster and the repository are in the same project. Is that the case?

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem, and was able to get it working by executing:

```sh
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding ${PROJECT} \
--member=serviceAccount:${EMAIL} \
--role=roles/artifactregistry.reader
```

with `${PROJECT}` = the project name and `${EMAIL}` = the default service account, e.g. something like `123456789012-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com`.

I suspect I may have removed some "excess permissions" too eagerly in the past.

Answer (score 2):

I think the tutorial is in error.

I was able to get this working by:

- Creating a Service Account and key
- Assigning the account Artifact Registry permissions
- Creating a Kubernetes secret representing the Service Account
- Using `imagePullSecrets`

```sh
PROJECT=[[YOUR-PROJECT]]
REPO=[[YOUR-REPO]]
LOCATION=[[YOUR-LOCATION]]

# Service Account and Kubernetes Secret name
ACCOUNT="artifact-registry" # Or ...

# Email address of the Service Account
EMAIL=${ACCOUNT}@${PROJECT}.iam.gserviceaccount.com

# Create Service Account
gcloud iam service-accounts create ${ACCOUNT} \
--display-name="Read Artifact Registry" \
--description="Used by GKE to read Artifact Registry repos" \
--project=${PROJECT}

# Create Service Account key
gcloud iam service-accounts keys create ${PWD}/${ACCOUNT}.json \
--iam-account=${EMAIL} \
--project=${PROJECT}

# Grant Service Account role to reader Artifact Reg
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding ${PROJECT} \
--member=serviceAccount:${EMAIL} \
--role=roles/artifactregistry.reader

# Create a Kubernetes Secret representing the Service Account
kubectl create secret docker-registry ${ACCOUNT} \
--docker-server=https://${LOCATION}-docker.pkg.dev \
--docker-username=_json_key \
--docker-password="$(cat ${PWD}/${ACCOUNT}.json)" \
--docker-email=${EMAIL} \
--namespace=d{NAMESPACE}
```

Then:

```sh
IMAGE="${LOCATION}-docker.pkg.dev/${PROJECT}/${REPO}/my-app:1.0.0"

echo "
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-app
  labels:
    app: my-app
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: ${ACCOUNT}
      containers:
      - name: my-app
        image: ${IMAGE}
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
" | kubectl apply --filename=- --namespace=${NAMESPACE}
```

> **NOTE** There are other ways to achieve this.
>
> You could use the cluster's default (Compute Engine) Service Account instead of a special-purpose Service Account as here but the default Service Account is more broadly used and granting it greater powers may be too broad.
>
> You could add the `imagePullSecrets` to the GKE namespace's default service account. This would give any deployment in that namespace the ability to pull from the repository and that may also be too broad.
>
> I think there's a GKE-specific way to grant a cluster service account GCP (!) roles.

Comment: I encountered the same problem, and was able to fix it using just the `gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding ...` line, without creating a new service account (i.e. just using the default service account). I suspect it may be due to me revoking "excess permissions" too eagerly. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!